# How do I get the signed document after the embedded signing ceremony completes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

Implementing a code of **Embedded Signing** in MVC C# Project. When I post for the sign document, It's redirecting to DocuSign page and it will redirect to return URL. using below code

```
private const string returnUrl = "http://localhost:5050/DSReturn";
...
return Redirect(viewUrl.Url);
```

Here I want to get that signed document in response instead of email. How this is possible? or is there any other way to get signed document after finish signature process?

Answer (score 2):

You would make the API call to the "document" resource (`.../documents/{documentId or constant}`).

The post-signing redirect URL is for the purposes of continuing your web workflow.  The "event" parameter allows your web application to generate the correct page or results.  For example, in the "Loan Co" example at the Dev Center generates a post-signing page that has links for the document, which in turn result in the API call to retrieve the document.  In a real-world integration, the redirect URL is not a reliable indicator that the envelope is "completed". For example, the signer could close the browser before the redirect was executed, or the envelope may have subsequent signers. The Connect service provides a much more reliable trigger for downloading the documents.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what @WTP mentioned, you have a couple of approaches. First is via a raw API call using the `/v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}` endpoint and retrieving the file from the response. More information can be found [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get).

Another option you may or may not be aware of is using the [DocuSign Client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) NuGet package. Your code would then look something like this pseudocode:

```
Stream documentStream = EnvelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, documentId);
```

If you are not using the NuGet package yet, keep in mind there is setup work that you will have to do to set-up the EnvelopesApi. That information can be found [here](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/config-and-auth).